# having problems with mergesort algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, merge, mergesort

I am currently trying to transcribe a mergesort algorithm from a pseudocode level to a working implementation in java. This is my code

```
public int[] merge(int a[], int b[]) {
        int c[] = new int[a.length + b.length];
        int i = 0, j = 0;
        for (int k = 0; k < c.length; k++) {
            if (a[i] <= b[j]) {
                c[k] = a[i++];
            } else {
                c[k] = b[j++];
            }
        }
        return c;
    }
```

The pseudocode interpretation is correct to the best of my knowledge but it keeps returning an ArrayOutofBound Exception.
Where did I get it all wrong.

Comment: Consider what happens when `a[a.length-1]` < `b[0]`: you run through the entire `a` array, increment `i` to `a.length`, and then try to compare a non-existent element in `a` with the first element of `b`. You need to actively check for the end of one array, and then just run through the other once that happens.

Comment: @dlev is right about the cause, though it's not an edge case at all.  No matter what happens, you will finish with one array before the other, and when that happens you need to be able to finish filling from the other array.

Comment: @MarkPeters Indeed, I did not mean to imply it was an edge case. I was just trying to use an "extreme" example to illustrate the point.

Answer (score 2):

This would obviously give the out of bound exception because you are not keeping track of the length of `a` and `b` arrays . Since `k = a + b` , `a` and `b` will always be less than `k` . Hence the exception.

And when you apply this check, remember to copy the remaining of the items, whether they are of `a[]` or `b[]` , to copy them to `c[]`. See this -

```
for(;i<a.length;i++)
    c[k++] = a[i++];

for(;j<b.length;b++)
    c[k++] = b[j++];
```

Answer (score 0):

The merge algorithm in the way you intend to implement it is a bit more elaborated, below you'll find a correct implementation:

```
public int[] merge(int a[], int b[]) {

    int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0;
    int m = a.length, n = b.length;
    int[] c = new int[m + n];

    // Merge to the end of one of the source arrays
    while (i < m && j < n) {
        if (a[i] <= b[j]) {
            c[k] = a[i];
            i++;
        } else {
            c[k] = b[j];
            j++;
        }
        k++;
    }

    // Determine which source array has elements remaining and
    // append those to the result array
    if (i < m) {
        for (int p = i; p < m; p++) {
            c[k] = a[p];
            k++;
        }
    } else {
        for (int p = j; p < n; p++) {
            c[k] = b[p];
            k++;
        }
    }

    return c;

}
```